# How to use View components in Visual Studio 17.5.0 in Linux

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, .net-7.0, view-components

ASP .NET 7 MVC core application uses view commponents in Razor Views like in _Layout.chtml

```
<vc:producttree roott="ProductTreeRoot">
</vc:producttree>
```

After upgrading Visual Studio from 17.4.5 to 17.5.0 and deploying application to Linux
view components are no more rendered. Markup in browser contains same <vc:producttree> element.
If application in running from VS IDE in windows, markup contains proper html.

If Visual Studio is reverted back to 17.4.5 and older net runtime in forced in global.js using

```
 {   "sdk": {
     "version": "7.0.103",
     "rollForward": "disable"   }
 }
```

view components are rendered in Linux also.
How to use views components in with .NET 7.0.200 and Visual Studio 17.5.0 ?

Related quiestion is in [Why View Component is not rendered in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75512661/why-view-component-is-not-rendered-in-production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that occurs in `.Net 7.0.200` and `Visual Studio 17.5.0`, If you don't want to use older net runtime, you can use:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("xxxx")
```

to render the view component.

refer to [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46740).

Comment: When using a ModelExpression parameter this method cannot be used as they only work with the tag helper.
´public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ModelExpression model, string pageCode, bool debug = false)´ How to use it in ´7.0.200´ ?

Comment: Sorry, Because ModelExpression parameter can only work with the tag helper, So I am afraid you can only use tag helper with older .net runtime to achieve it until this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Oh great, two hours wasted wondering what the hell I did wrong. Nice work Microsoft.